# Is there a way to return all successful promises from fetch until one fails?

Tags: javascript, promise

The Javascript function [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) waits for all resolved or rejected promises to finish. [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) won't return the resolved promises if any of them are rejected, and [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) and [Promise.any](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) only give the *first* settled or fufilled promise.

Is there a way to send off multiple promises (say 100), and then as soon as one fails (perhaps have 20 succeed) cancel the unsettled promises (of which there are 100 - 20 - 1 = 79  not yet settled)? I don't even need the details of which failed, but just a sort of Promise.someSettled function.

For context, I'm mapping between data and fetch calls, and I'd like to know what fetches need to be retried.

Is that possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to build a progress indicator for a large number of async calls; it would be good to mention that in your question.

Comment: Promises don't have a mechanism to be cancelled. Besides that, what are you trying to build here? Promises might not be the right tool for you.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if none of the promises fails?

Comment: Probably just me but the two statements "don't even need the details of which failed" and "know what fetches need to be retried" appear to be at odds with each other.

Comment: If the goal is to retry failed fetches, then all you need is to apply a retry pattern to every fetch individually. Reading between the lines, that's what you want but with the additional requirement that retrying ceases when some arbitrary number of fetches (or their retries) have been successful.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I'd like to retry in bulk, but first I need to collect all the successful ones first.

Comment: @Pureferret, that doesn't make sense when you may need to rely on retries to get even a single success.

Comment: @roamer in my exact case I don't think that's applicable (the first ~20 succeed, then the remaining ones took a long time to be rejected.). Even then, I can work out which to retry whether it's all of them or just a few.

Comment: @Pureferret, in that case maybe you want "batch try", "batch retry", "batch retry" ... until the required number of successes is reached. That would be a rather odd and rather inefficient approach but it could be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Because the input promises and output resolve values aren't one-to-one, I think the easiest way to manage this would be to just push to an outer array on resolve, and use `Promise.all` to wait for one rejection, something like:

```js
const makePromises = () => Array.from(
  { length: 100 },
  (_, i) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() > 0.05) resolve(i);
      else reject();
    }, 1000 * Math.random());
  })
);

const resolveValues = [];
Promise.all(
  makePromises()
    .map(prom => prom.then(val => {
      resolveValues.push(val);
    }))
)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Unexpected - All promises resolved');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    const innerResolveValues = [...resolveValues];
    console.log('Done:');
    console.log(innerResolveValues);
  });
```

Comment: Mapping and pushing is really smart.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to build a progress indicator for a large number of calls.

A simple solution would be to break the large number of calls into smaller groups and use `Promise.allSettled()` to determine when each group is finished. You can then compare the number of finished groups to the number of unfinished groups to get a measurement of progress.

Comment: That's a good work around for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, @Certainperformance hit it on the head! Here is another way of assembling the array of promises but the idea is exactly the same:

```js
for (var acc=[], pr=[], i=0; i<100; i++)
  pr.push(new Promise((rs,rj)=>setTimeout((i<20?rs:rj).bind(null,i),200*i))
    .then(d=>{acc.push(d)}))
Promise.all(pr).then(
 d=>{console.log("all done!", acc)},
 e=>{console.log("with some errors:", acc)} );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

In my example I let the first finishing promises succeed and reject the later ones (for `i>=20`). The promises finish in a sequence of 0.2s one after another. So, after 4.2 seconds the first rejected promise is returned and the "failure" branch of the outer `.then()` will be executed, listing the accumulated successful promises in `acc`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's add a generator into the mix ;)

That way we don't have to wait for all Promises to resolve or one to throw before we can process the successful items.

```js
const makePromises = () => Array.from({
    length: 100
  },
  (_, i) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(Math.random() > 0.05 ? resolve : reject, 1000 * Math.random(), i);
  })
);

// Takes anything iterable as long as it's syncronously iterable 
// and a finite list.
async function* asTheyResolve(promises) {
  let itemsLeft = 0,
    deferred;

  const init = (resolve, reject) => (deferred = { resolve, reject });
  // shove my result into the promise that is currently awaited
  const resolve = (value) => deferred.resolve(value);
  const reject = (error) => deferred.reject(error);

  for (let item of promises) {
    itemsLeft++;
    Promise.resolve(item).then(resolve, reject);
  }

  while (itemsLeft-- > 0) {
    // creates a new Promise and awaits it.
    yield await new Promise(init);
  }
}


(async () => {
  try {
    const start = performance.now();
    for await (let value of asTheyResolve(makePromises())) {
      console.log("time: %f value: %o", performance.now() - start, value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("one has thrown", error);
  }
})();
```